# ASP.NET MVC - where should my function put? Controller? Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

For example, I have a password generator in my user registration website. Where should I put the function of generating password?
Put together with UserController?

What is the correct way to put these functions?

Comment: I would create a helper class with static methods which operate on the password generation/encryption etc...

Comment: It depends. Does it need to be reused? Does the implementation for how a password (hash I presume) is generated need to be swapped out i.e. change algorithms?

Comment: It will be reused in other area. How to create helper class with static methods???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting it into a class of its own. For the sake of SRP, your UserModel should do things with a User and only a User. Your UserModel class should not be responsible for generating passwords for new users. Separate it into its own class and call a method on that class during the creation of your new user in your UserModel.

Comment: You suggest putting in Controller?

Comment: I agree with this comment.  What if in the future you want a windows service to generate a password, why on would it use the `public class UserModel { }` instead of a `public class PasswordGenerator { }`?

Comment: Well you're generating passwords for Users, so why wouldn't you put it in your User Model?

Comment: Generating a password does not necessarily have anything to do with a user, so it's good practice to create [separate models for each concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in my User Model.

Or you could create a Utility class and put it in there.

Comment: I like the Utility Class idea.